# UnityEditor is Vector3 within scene view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to see if a `Vector3` is in within the viewing area of the `Scene`, and not on the other side of the object either (aka objects not visible to the camera)? So, for instance:

```
public void OnSceneGUI(){
    Handles.color = Color.red;
    Camera camera = Camera.current;
    foreach(Vector3 handle in handles){
        Vector3 point = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(handle);
        if(point.x > 0 && point.x < 1 && point.y > 0 && point.y < 1){
            RaycastHit hit;
            Vector3 fwd = camera.transform.TransformDirection(handle);
            if (Physics.Raycast(camera.transform.position, fwd, out hit)){
                Debug.Log("here");
                //if(Vector3.Distance(camera.transform.position, handle);
                Handles.FreeMoveHandle(handle, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will check to see if the vector 3 is in view, but it also includes things that are on the opposite side of the same object.

Comment: When you say the opposite side - do you mean occluded by a mesh? Say your view is blocked by a door, and the point is farther from the camera than the door, so you do not have a direct line of sight. You want to count that point? Or are you referring to points behind the camera, or out of range?

Comment: The door example would be correct, I don't want to include it if it is behind a door, or if your looking at a persons stomach you wouldn't see their back, so don't include those either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! there is at least one easy way, maybe two!

You could use Raycast. In order for Raycast to work you will need the occluding object to have a Collider of some sort (Mesh, Box, Collider2D, etc).
Then use Raycast from the camera to the Vector3. If it hits anything in between you will get a collision.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

You might also be able to use Renderer.IsVisible if there is an object at that Vector3 position. That would work for very small objects. Not sure how it would work with partially visible meshes.

"http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html

Comment: What I am doing is creating a mesh modifier, and currently I am creating `Handles` on all the meshes vertices if it is in the viewport. The issue is that it is displaying `Handles` on the backside of the mesh, which bogs down the editor. Since the backside of the mesh isn't seen I don't want to create handles there until it is seen. So I don't think isVisible will work. This means raycast might work...

Comment: So basically if it hits something other than that Vector3, than it is considered hidden (aka the front of the body)

Comment: @TheBoogieMan Raycasts are very expensive to begin with, and doing one for each vertex will always be slow.

Comment: @K.L. what about linecasts? I am using that.

Comment: Based on your "handles" idea, if you handles are also rotated, you could possibly use the measure of distance in some cases. If the object is farther away than a certain point you may be able to know it should be hidden. Also check the orientation of the the object: What is its "Forward" to see if the object is facing away from the camera.